# Is it possible to communicate between 2 gRPC services in one ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, grpc

There is a solution of 3 projects (client (.NET WPF), server (ASP.NET Core gRPC (will run as a Windows service)), agent (.NET Console application (runs on the same PC as the server, but in user session)).

The server must have 2 separate services (one that communicates with the remote client and one that communicates with the local agent).

When a client's request is received, the server "forwards" it to the agent, the latter executes the request and returns the answer to the server, and then the server sends this answer to the client that asked for it.

Is it possible to implement this? And if so, how? I don't understand it at all...

P.S: I need it for the client to get screenshots from the server, but since the server is a Windows service, it cannot take those screenshots. The idea is that if the client asks the server to "ask" the agent to take a screenshot and send it to him, then the server will send the screenshot to the client.

Client-server (bidirectional streaming)
Agent-server (bidirectional streaming)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but from your description but it doesn't sound like you have 1 application, but 3 (client, server, agent). I would assume that the agent responds to the server over the same channel that the request came in on so the agent doesn't really need to know about the server. The same is probably true for the client to server interaction so the server doesn't need to know about the client. This is how normal client/server interactions happen and the server just responds to the client on the incoming connection without any specific knowledge about the client.

Comment: @phuzi I added a little more to the question to make it clearer what I need it for

Comment: So, the server will host one of the GRPC services and the agent will host the other one. The client will be a client of the server's service and the server will be a client of the agent's service. This is fairly standard stuff and don't see why the agent would need to know specifics about the server or why tihe server would need to know the specifics of the client.

Comment: @phuzi Can you point me in the right direction? Can you give me a link to the right material? I'm just new to technology like gRPC, and don't really understand some things. I understand the client-server interaction, but the client-server-agent interaction I don't really understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow you are describing is fairly straight-forward and is similar to how HTTP proxies proxy browser requests.

Run the snippet below you will see the flow I'm describing where the client makes a request to the server, the server then forwards the request on to the agent. The agent then responds to the request from the server using the same connection as the request from the server, and the server responds to the client using the same connection the client sent the request over.

[image: client-server-agent request flow]